# WPF: binding elements in main window and user control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls, command

I am new to WPF and MVVM and not sure how to solve this (probbaly simple) problem. I have a MainWindow with two regions: RibbonView and below it a TabControl (Telerik). I have big buttons in the ribbon control which are always enabled. For example, I have a button "Tenants" and when I click on this button I create a new tab item and place my TenantControl containing a GridView control (also from Telerik). Its content is automatically loaded.

Now I want to get the following to work: additionally I have some small buttons (Add, Delete, Clone etc) (Ribbon control) that are disabled by default and I want to enable these buttons when I select an item in a grid. Is the using of routed commands the proper way to solve the problem? How to enable a button in a main window if I select an item in a grid in own user control? And yes in a main window I have a reference to the user control. No need for code just a concept is needed - as I said before I am completelly new to WPF/MVVM.

Thanks for any help and best regards,
Erno

Answer (score 0):

In my WPF Applications, I often use `RibbonBar`s as well, but instead of creating different `TabItem`s for the different views, I display them all in one place by using a `ContentControl` and then just changing the `Content` value to different view models which are then rendered as the relevant views:

In `Mainview`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

...

In `MainViewModel`:

```
ViewModel = new SomethingViewModel();
```

...

In App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SomethingViewModel}">
    <Views:SomethingView />
</DataTemplate>
```

In my `MainViewModel` class, I have a helper method:

```
private bool IsViewModelOfType<T>()
{
    return ViewModel != null && ViewModel.GetType() == typeof(T);
}
```

This method is used in the `ICommand.CanExecute` property to enable and disable `Command`s dependant on the loaded view model:

```
public ICommand CopyTrackList
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => ClipboardManager.SetClipboardText(
        ((ReleaseLabelCopyViewModel)ViewModel).TrackList), canExecute => 
        IsViewModelOfType<ReleaseLabelCopyViewModel>() &&
        ((ReleaseLabelCopyViewModel)ViewModel).SomePropertyInChildViewModel == true); }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sheridan,

thanks for the quick response. I need actually tabs. Each of them contains another user control and I need the way to access ribbon buttons from it. As described in my question, I need to enable a button within the ribbon control (within a main window) when I select an item in a grid which is contained in a user control. In the main wodow I have references to the different views which reference further to viewmodels.

Thanks,
Erno

Comment: I edited my last code example... now the `canExecute` part of the `ICommand` checks if this certain view model is currently loaded and then it checks whether the `SomePropertyInChildViewModel` property is true *before* it enables the `ICommand` in the `RibbonBar`. You can do the same and expose a `bool` property from your child view model that represents whether the item is selected in your `Grid` or not. Also, you don't *need* to use `TabItem`s... there is nothing that you can do with your `TabItem`s that I can't do with my setup... still, it's up to you.

Comment: I suppose you place your commands in the view where your commands are used. Is this correct?

Comment: These `ICommand`s are declared in the view models and utilised in the views through data binding to the `Command` properties on `Button`s and other relevant controls.

Comment: Hi,I cannot find any ActionCommand? There are some other type of commands like RoutedCommand/RoutedUICommand etc but no command like ActionCommand. I couldn't find any details about this action type...

Comment: Sorry... `ActionCommand` is my own version of a `RelayCommand`... it's kind of like an `ICommand delegate`. See the [RelayCommand.cs](https://gist.github.com/schuster-rainer/2648922) page on GitHub for a similar implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ;-). I got it working now. Not sure whether this is the best way - see my anser below ;-).